# Как обновить виджет в Android в заданное время используя AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, виджет, android-widgets

У меня есть виджет, который требуется обновлять каждый день в заданное время. Я попытался реализовать это через AlarmManager, но виджет не обновляется.

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context),
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class)));
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Widget.ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Widget.ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
        updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Похоже у вас Intent неправильно создается, нужно так. Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class); 
     intent.setAction(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
 Попробуйте, если поможет я перенесу в ответ.

Comment: @Style-7 да, помогло. Благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже у вас `Intent` неправильно создается, нужно так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
```