# Не могу передать данные в виджет

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widgets

У меня есть приложение которое с сервера получает информацию и добавляет ее на экран, с этим все хорошо. Нужно чтобы приложение добавляла эту же информацию в виджет, информация получается приложение выводит информацию в тост, но не отображается на виджете.

```
class NewAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
private fun xmlParse(str:String, views: RemoteViews, context: Context)
{
    val parser= XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser()
    parser.setInput(str.reader())
    var eventType=parser.eventType

    val tags= Stack<String>()
    var RecordCode=0
    var Buy=""
    var Sell=""
    var Date=""
    var Records= emptyList<Record>().toMutableList()

    while (eventType!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {

        when(eventType)
        {


            XmlPullParser.START_TAG->
            {
                tags.push(parser.name)
                when(parser.name)
                {
                    "Record"->
                    {
                        RecordCode=parser.getAttributeValue("","Code").toInt()
                        Date=parser.getAttributeValue("","Date")
                    }


                }
            }
            XmlPullParser.TEXT->
            {
                when(tags.peek())
                {
                    "Buy"->
                    {
                        Buy=parser.text
                    }
                    "Sell"->
                    {
                        Sell=parser.text
                    }
                }
            }
            XmlPullParser.END_TAG->
            {
                when(parser.name)
                {
                    "Record"->
                    {
                        Records.add(Record(RecordCode,Date,Buy,Sell))
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        eventType=parser.next()
    }
    Toast.makeText(context,Records[Records.count()-1].RecordDate , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, "77")
}



@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private  fun GetMetal(context: Context, views: RemoteViews)
{
    val format= DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val date= LocalDateTime.now()
    val dateTime2= date.format(format)
    var period = Period.of(0, 0, 2)
    val dateTime1=date.minus(period).format(format)
    val url="http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/xml_metall.asp?date_req1=$dateTime1&date_req2=$dateTime2"
    val queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val stringRequest= StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,url,
        {response->xmlParse(response, views, context)
            Toast.makeText(context, "ii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }, { Toast.makeText(context, "Ошибка на сервере", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()})

    queue.add(stringRequest)

}
private fun g(views: RemoteViews)
{
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text,"54545")
}
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int
) {
    val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)+"5"
    val widgetText2 = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)+"2"
    val widgetText3 = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)+"3"
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.new_app_widget)
   // views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)
     views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text2,widgetText2)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text3,widgetText3)
   GetMetal(context, views)

    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text3, widgetText)
    //g(views)
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    sleep(300)
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
```

Нужно чтобы виджет обновлялся каждый день, тоже не совсем понимаю, как это сделать.

Comment: Виджет обновляют посылкой широковещательно сообщения (читайте оф. док.). "Засыпание" в методе updateAppWidget уберите. Обновляется виджет по расписанию через Alarm Manager посылкой в свой приемник, там через AppWidgetManager получаете все ids виджетов и обновляете их также.

Comment: Если честно слабо понятно как это все происходит

Comment: [тык](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/configuration#update) [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325678/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-android-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-alarmmanager/1325957#1325957)